# Auth::attempt not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I've read dozens of similar posts, still cant't make it work. I always get the 'login failed' message.
This is my users table

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
first_name varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
last_name varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
slug varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
email varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
password varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
remember_token varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

See password field is 255, so large enough for hashing.

Here is my App\Model\User class

```
namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
}
```

This is the login controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function getLogin()
    {
        return view('backend.login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt([
            'email'    => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password')
        ])) {
            echo 'login successful'; exit();
        }
        else {
            echo 'login failed'; exit();
        }
    }
}
```

User records in db were inserted with their password set to

```
Crypt::encrypt('123456')
```

This gave me nearly 200 chaacters long hashed passwords stored in the db (is that normal?)

My config.app file says

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY'),
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

And finally here is my config.auth file

```
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Model\User::class,
        ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];
```

I tried to dump $request->input('email')/$request->input('password') from the form, and everything is as expected.
I tried to dump the query log and the query seems to be right ('select * from users where email = ? limit 1, with correct email field binding).

What else can I check?
Is there a way to "deeply inspect" Auth::attempt to check what's going wrong over there?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is you are using `Crypt::encrypt('123456')` to set user password.
`Crypt` is not used for this purpose as it requires `Decrypt` to work which is not implemented in `Auth` class

Simpy use `Hash` to hash password before you save to database

Example:

```
User::create([ 
    'password' => Hash::make('123456'),
    'username' => 'hitman'
]);
```

You can also do hashing in user model by adding this to `User` model class:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $salt = md5(str_random(64) . time());
    $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($password);
    $this->attributes['salt'] = $salt;
}
```

And later you can simply do this:

```
User::create([ 
    'password' => '123456', //hashing will be done in model
    'username' => 'hitman'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one helps you

```
Hash::make($data['password'])
```